# Why is the vertex attribute for normal vector not working?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I'm trying to implement diffuse lighting with OpenGL. I've debugged the fragment shader for a cube and found that the normal vector is always (0,0,0), even though I specify normals in my vertex data and enable the vertex attribute.

Relevant OpenGL code:

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,

-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,

-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,

0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,

-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,

-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f
};

GLuint VBO, boxVAO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &boxVAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

glBindVertexArray(boxVAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal;
out vec3 FragPos;
out vec3 outNormal;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 proj;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = proj * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0);
    FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(position, 1.0f));
    outNormal = vec3(normal);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core
in vec3 FragPos;
in vec3 outNormal;
out vec4 color;

uniform vec3 objectColor;
uniform vec3 lightColor;
uniform vec3 lightPos;

void main()
{
    float ambientIntensity = 0.5f;
    vec3 ambientColor = ambientIntensity * lightColor;

    vec3 norm = normalize(outNormal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos - FragPos);
    float diffuse = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuseColor = diffuse * lightColor;

    vec3 resultColor = (ambientColor + diffuseColor) * objectColor;
    color = vec4(resultColor, 1.0f);
}
```

Output: (only shows ambient lighting, no diffuse)

[image]

Also, not sure if this helps at all, but doing something weird like setting the normal as the fragments position yields this result:
[image]

So it seems like the the normals should be producing diffuse light, but are somehow not getting loaded into the shader correctly. Any ideas?

This is the code I used to debug the shader:

```
// debug testing
vec3 test = vec3(outNormal.xyz);
bvec3 ln = lessThan(test, vec3(0,0,0));
if (ln[2]){
    color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}else{
    color = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: What's the position of the Light in this image? All your code *as-is* looks correct, which leads me to believe that there's a problem with how you've positioned the light or the cubes—which also explains why feeding weird values as your normals causes odd results.

Comment: The light is at (1.2, 1.0, 2.0) and the main cube is at (0,0,0). So in the image above, the light is closer to the camera than the cube is, so the diffuse light should be visible in the screenshot.

Comment: Just to clarify, the small lighter cube represents the light, and uses different shaders that shouldn't be relevant to this problem. It is just used to show the light source position.

Comment: "*I've debugged the fragment shader for a cube and found that the normal vector is always (0,0,0),*" How did you make this determination?

Comment: I added code in the bottom of the fragment shader to change the final color based on a condition. It is tedious but the only way I can see to debug GLSL. I edited the original post to show the code I used. (change the test vector to the one you want to test, and the other vector against it, and ln contains the boolean of the conditional results). Then I put in various values (0 and 0.1 usually) to test the resulting color). I concluded that normals were always (0,0,0) based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops! Turns out when I created the light VAO, I used the same vertices but only used the first three values of each vertex for position (which is correct for the light). But I accidentally used that VAO for drawing the cube instead of the VAO shown in the code above. Can't believe I did not catch that.. Anyway, the code here is correct.

Peace.